# Properly analyze Azure logs

Tags: database, azure, testing, scaling, blazemeter

I have conducted a performance testing a on a e-commerce website hosted on Azure. And I am checking azure logs for the test duration to find some scaling issues. From the logs I saw a lot of "InProc" dependencies failure. Also a lot of "Technical exception" with message " Cart not recalculated for remove shipping methods". So I would like to if this indicates any scaling issues or what should check or scaling issues for example slow database queries. I am very much new in performance testing and Azure so any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are querying every record or using some clauses to select the data. what is the size of select query. Could you please confirm if the Azure dbs  and are in same region or not?

Comment: Hi, I actually conducted performance testing. So I sent a lot of request to the site from JMeter and then also checking azure logs for the duration of the test to find any performance issue. CPU and Network usage was stable but I still got high response time. So I think there must be problem with the slow database queries. For example in azure log i find "GET/api/invoices/{orderId}"  query takes a lot of time. So what can i conclude from this??

Comment: if there are proper indexes on table- Is that `orderId` a primary key in the table. Please confirm if it is a Azure SQL DB the youe can run the performance recommendation, under the `Intelligence Performance`.

Answer (score 1):

Performance can be improved using [Cache-Aside pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cache-aside)- Caching Can Improve Application Performance

Data from a data store can be loaded into a cache on demand. This can assist increase performance while also ensuring data consistency between the cache and the underlying data storage.

> Read-through and write-through/write-behind actions are available in
> many commercial caching systems. An application in these systems
> retrieves data by referring to the cache. If the data isn't already in
> the cache, it's fetched and added from the data store. Any changes to
> the data in the cache are also automatically pushed back to the data
> store.
>
> It is the duty of the programmes that utilise the cache to retain the
> data if the cache does not provide this feature.
>
> The cache-aside technique allows an application to mimic the
> capabilities of read-through caching. This technique stores data in
> the cache only when it is needed. The following diagram shows how to
> use the Cache.